# XML, LINQ parsing

Tags: linq-to-xml

I am modifying my XML using LINQ:

```
Dim feedXML As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(m_xmld.OuterXml.ToString())
Dim SortedFields = From field In feedXML.Descendants("fields")
Dim sFieldList = From field In SortedFields.Descendants("field") Order By
                 Integer.Parse(field.@position)
```

I am trying to sort my "fields" in ascending order. Now my problem is I want the sorted fields to replace my unsorted fields list in the XML so that I can use the sorted XML further.

How can I retrieve the XML after the sorting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no real concept of "the XML after the sorting". If you've *only* got field elements, it's relatively easy - but if you've got:

```
 <field position="2" />
 <non-field />
 <field position="1" />
 <non-field />
 <field position="0" />
```

then what should the result be afterwards?

Comment: Nope, Basically what I want to know is after I am done with modifying the nxml(i.e sorting the fields in the node "fields") i want to modified xml to do some other operations, how can i get the modified xml?

Comment: There *isn't* any modified XML. You haven't been sorting the XML itself - you've been sorting a list fetched from the XML. That's my point. You haven't been changing the XML itself at all. Given the example in my answer, what do you want the result to be?

Comment: Sorry if i framed the question in a wrong way,yes, I am sorting the list fetched from the xml. Now i want this list to replaced the unsorted list in my original xml so that I can use it.

Thanks

Comment: So what do you want the result to be in my example? Or will the XML only have the field elements?

Comment: I have other elements in the xml
< report>
< sql >
< fields>
< field position="1"/>
< field position="3"/>
< field position="2"/>
</fields>
</sql>
</report>

Now i am soring the <fields> node , so now i want this sorted nodelist to replace the unsorted list in the original xml.

Comment: I want the following result.

 <field position="0" />
 <non-field />
 <field position="1" />
 <non-field />
 <field position="2" />

Comment: Okay. I'll see whether I can work out a way of doing that. It's likely to be a bit of a pain, to be honest...

Comment: Hey Jon, thanks for your help. I figured it out, my mentor had written something which i used to make it work.

Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 0):

I used `ReplaceNodes` for this in the end:

```
x.ReplaceNodes(
    from el in x.Elements()
    orderby (int)el.Element("Index")
    select el                               
);
```